# joomla template creation help

Tags: joomla

.I am creating my own template in joomla, following the tutorial from lynda.com. but i am stuck on dividing the component for the designated value of column and intro article to be displayed.

.what code do i need to divide my `<jdoc:include type="component" />` into certain number of columns whenever i set how many i desire to have when using category blog. because right now my `<jdoc:include type="component" />` does not divide into 3 columns whenever i set 3 columns on my category blog options. it's just producing rows for every article in my category blog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the stylesheet and/or the category blog file. Take a look at your current output. If you have 3 containers each with its own article, then you need to change the CSS so that the containers display as 3-wide columns. If you do not, then you need to make a copy of /components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php and place it in templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php. Make an edits you need to that file so you don't lose any changes when you update.